# How do I style an HTML `legend` element as a table cell in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css

How do I style an HTML `legend` element as a table cell in Mozilla Firefox? (I can't figure out how to do this in any browser, but I only need the functionality for Firefox.)

I need this functionality to align multiple `legend` elements in multiple `fieldset` elements as if they were `th` and `tr` elements, respectively.

The following code is an example where the second through sixth `div` elements demonstrate the desired layout that I can't seem to achieve with `legend` and `fieldset`.

There's an undesired line break after the `legend` element that I can't seem to get rid of and which shouldn't be there given `display: table-cell` styles.

```css
* {
  all: unset;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  all: unset;
}

html {
  margin: 3rem;
}

style {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

body > div {
  display: table;
}

fieldset,
body > div > div {
  display: table-row;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

legend,
span,
div > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<h1>bad: tabular <code>fieldset</code> and <code>legend</code></h1>
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><label for="checkbox.1">Label for Checkbox</label></legend>
    <span><input id="checkbox.1" type="checkbox"></span>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><label for="checkbox.2">Label for Checkbox; Checkboxes Should Line Up</label></legend>
    <span><input id="checkbox.2" type="checkbox"></span>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<h1>good: tabular <code>div</code> and <code>div</code></h1>
<div>
  <div>
    <div><label for="checkbox.3">Label for Checkbox</label></div>
    <span><input id="checkbox.3" type="checkbox"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><label for="checkbox.3">Label for Checkbox; Checkboxes Should Line Up</label></div>
    <span><input id="checkbox.3" type="checkbox"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to the HTML `legend` tag.

```css
* {
  all: unset;
}
html {
  margin: 3rem;
}
style {
  display: none;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
fieldset,
body > div {
  display: table-row;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
legend,
span,
div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
legend {
  float: left;
}
input {
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<h1>bad: tabular <code>fieldset</code> and <code>legend</code></h1>
<fieldset>
  <legend><label for="checkbox.1">Label for Checkbox</label></legend><span><input id="checkbox.1" type="checkbox"></span>
</fieldset>
<h1>good: tabular <code>div</code> and <code>div</code></h1>
<div>
  <div><label for="checkbox.2">Label for Checkbox</label></div>
  <span><input id="checkbox.2" type="checkbox"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this only superficially styles the `legend` element as a table cell. I've updated my code example for clarity. Checkboxes (or other form controls) should line up if there are multiple fieldsets, which is a feature specific to table cells.